# value of this inside return this.each(function() { } )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie to javascript. and i have a Jquery question .

Suppose i have a plugin , popup.js and i am calling the plugin as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#pop-it').modal('hide'); 
               });
```

in my plugin code i have the following code :

```
function modal(option , _relatedtarget) {
     console.log(this);   // 1st console.log
    return this.each(function() {
      console.log(this);  // 2nd console.log
    });
  }
```

the value i get for the 1st console,log is

```
Object { 0: <div#pop-it.modal.fade>, length: 1, context: HTMLDocument → pop-it.html, selector: "#pop-it" }
```

and the value i get for the 2nd console.log is:

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="pop-it" class="modal fade" style="display: none;">
```

why the different results ??

**My 2nd question :**

also is't the context of this supposed to change before

```
return this.each(function() {

});
```

since its a new function definition ??

Comment: @everyone , made some edits , there were some mistakes in the question , please read it again .

Comment: [**Read the docs!**](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the immediate scope of a jQuery plugin `this` is a jQuery object, which means you don't have to wrap it.

Generally you would do

```
$(this).each(function() { ...
```

but in a jQuery plugin you can do

```
this.each(function() { ...
```

because `this` is already a jQuery wrapper/collection object.

On the other hand, inside an [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) callback function `this` is **not** a jQuery object, it's the native DOM node, so to get the same result you would have to do

```
$.fn.plugin = function() {

    console.log(this); // jQuery object

    this.each(function() {
        console.log( $(this) ) // jQuery object

        console.log( this ) // native DOM node
    });
});
```

Comment: why is it that `In the immediate scope of a jQuery plugin this is a jQuery object`  ?

Comment: Because that's how it works, jQuery passes the object into the plugin as a jQuery object, not the native DOM nodes it contains. This is so data, events and other things that are bound to the jQuery object is passed to any plugin etc. as well.

Answer (score 0):

You get two different results because the value of `this` depends on how the function it is inside is called. You have two different functions. They each get their own value for `this`.